# Remove duplicate filezilla site manager entries

Tags: filezilla

I use filezilla across multiple computers and often export and re-import the site manager entries on to my laptop. It's filled with duplicates, i'd like to remove them. The export file is XML and the method of storing the passwords has changed between versions of filezilla from clear text to base64 encoded. Each duplicate site name in the list is one thing that's common between each duplicated entry. Is there anyway to clean up these duplicate entries?

All I could think of if there's no way was to write a basic XML parsing script to remove duplicates based on that field.

Comment: Can you post a redacted sample of the XML? Someone (myself or otherwise) can probably give you a regex rule to clean it up.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I would write a script in PHP to parse the XML, no need to use regex

Comment: OK, then what exactly are you asking us?

Comment: If there's any built in function or program to do it for filezilla xml files.